# Why are baseball team names considered as plural nouns?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

I learned company names are considered as singular.

> Amazon.com, Inc. is an American multinational technology company which focuses on e-commerce, cloud computing, digital streaming, and artificial intelligence.
>
> [Amazon — Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_(company))

However, baseball team names seem to be plural.

> The San Francisco Giants are an American professional baseball team based in San Francisco.
>
> [San Francisco Giants — Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Giants)

> The Yankees have not participated in an arbitration hearing since 2017
>
> ['It’s all business': Judge, Yanks set for arb hearing — MLB.com](https://www.mlb.com/news/aaron-judge-yankees-set-for-arbitration-hearing)

What is the difference between company names and baseball team names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sports team names often refer to *all the members of the team collectively*, so "the Yankees" is "the players of the Yankees baseball team." Conversely, when speaking about some corporation, it is usually the corporate identity that people have in mind, which is singular.

Comment: This not the case in British English, where corporations, companies, teams, etc, can all be referred to in the plural.

Comment: One reason is that the names **themselves** are plural. "The Yankees is ..." is just awful English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Those particular teams have chosen plural names. British football teams usually take their name from the town or district, e.g. Liverpool, Derby County (officially followed by 'Football Club', therefore singular), but may have a plural nickname (Derby County is 'The Rams', from a folk song 'The Derby Ram').